# Better performant alternatives of JSON on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, deserialization

I am building a webgl application. And it requires deserialization of data ~15MB (this is size of a single object, I will have around 10 of those in my application) and the bigger portion (90%) of this data is a few arrays of floating point numbers and these arrays need to be deserialized into Float32Arrays in JavaScript.

Currently I am using JSON. Since my data contains lots of repeating numbers it is highly compressible and I am happy with the network performance. Besides. I am also happy with it's performance on desktop. However loading, deserialization of the data into plain JS arrays and then converting them to Float32Arrays on mobile devices takes a lot of time.

I considered using protobuff but I saw this on https://protobuffers.codeplex.com/

> Protocol Buffers are not designed to handle large messages. If you are
>   dealing in messages larger than a megabyte each, it may be time to
>   consider an alternate strategy.

So what can I do to improve performance of my application. What SERDES methods should I test?

Please walk me through this process and help me test my alternatives, I'll put more details if you ask anything in the comments section.

Comment: Have you had a look at BSON?

Comment: @Bergi I'll check that one out now!

Comment: Is the 15MB the size of the JSON serialised data, or the size of the data in memory after having been deserialised? According to http://bsonspec.org/spec.html it looks like BSON stores 64bit floats, not 32bit, which is a pity. Protocol Buffers have a double and a float, so for your 32bit float arrays that might be more compact that BSON and stands a good chance of being faster.

Comment: @bazza it's the size of JSON. However, compactness is not my concern at the moment. The loading/deserialization of the data on mobile device  is painfully slow even in local environment.

Comment: Evil idea: get the server to send the source code to make the typed arrays, then run `eval`. This would save the intermediate step.

Answer (score 2):

If your Object is like one big Array of floats, you could send the raw bytes instead of a JSON-encoded string.

`XMLHttpRequest` has `responseType = "arraybuffer"`. With that your "parsing-step" is reduced to `var floats = new Float32Array(xhr.response)`.

And it would even reduce the impact of this task to the memory, because you don't need to keep a 15MB big String + an intermediate Array containing maybe about 20MB of doubles, i guess + the resulting Float32Array containing another 10MB *(half of the doubles)* all at about the same time.

You have 1 ArrayBuffer containing only the raw bytes + a Float32Array that references this data in memory.

---

If this doesn't work for you, maybe you could explain the nature/structure of the data, that you send around.

Or maybe the code you use in the backend, if the serialization is the Problem.